# Photoshop CS5: duplicate layers with “smart objects”

Tags: photoshop

Not sure if I'm in the right place. If not, please direct me!

I'd like to make use of photoshop's "Smart Objects" to have an easier time managing my layers. I have about 20 layers that will be duplicated 10 times... and I'd rather manipulate them as single objects than as 20 layers each.

I created a smart object out of the 20 layers... when I duplicated the smart object, and edited to newly duplicated object... any edits also affected the original.

Is there a way to make distinct smart objects out of duplicates so they can be edited independently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the 20 layers first, then make each group into its own smart object (duplicating the smart object itself will only create another instance of the original).

You can also use **smart objects within smart objects.** This makes it akin to a class system or CSS styling -- each smart object can have the same general abstract template by  using instances of the same internal smart objects, then they can be made different as needed by including different elements to the separate top level objects. The top level smart objects should all be created separately, not duplicated. Inner objects that stay the same should be duplicated.

If selecting all the layers is a hassle, use the "**Layer Groups**" (folder icon next to new layer icon at the bottom of the "layers" panel)

Select all 20 layers and drag them to the folder icon. This will group the layers.

Now duplicate the group by dragging it onto the " **New Layer**" icon.

Now you should have two originals to work with. Just make sure you keep track of which is which.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new smart obj via copy. That will copy the smart obj content but it will be a "new" one. So if you make any modification in the new one it will stay only there.

To do that just right click on the smart obj in layers panel and choose "New smart object via copy" :)

Comment: +1 for the "New smart object via copy", Was searching for that command!